# Laravel: Schedule tasks using Beanstalkd

Tags: php, laravel-4, jobs, beanstalkd

My aim is to schedule and run a task every day at midnight. I already use Beanstalkd in my application for other scheduling purposes. But running a job every day at a specific time seems to be a bit difficult.

I schedule the job to run at 00:00 every day in my `global.php` file:

```
Queue::later($secondsBeforeMidNight, $jobToFire, array('data' => $data));
```

However, the thing about Laravel is that it boots up the entire application every time a request is received. Meaning, the above task would be scheduled every time a new request comes in. This will result in creating a myriad of jobs waiting to be fired at midnight.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `cron` for this - not Beanstalkd.

For Laravel 4 the best option is to use the Dispatcher package: https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher

This will allow you to schedule specific artisan commands to run at various times.

Comment: Ha, that's too bad. I think I'll go for crontab instead of adding a new package altogether just for one job. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Yeah - if it is just one job use cron. But once you start having 3,4,5 jobs - its definitely worth switching...